# In a multiple criteria dropdown filter, how do I display resulting content?

Tags: javascript, html

I have built out a filter that allows me to narrow down criteria based on the option selected in the first menu. Once the second option is selected, I'm unable to show content based on that criteria.

**What am I missing?**

```js
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName("article");

var years = {
  news: [2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012],
  analysis: [2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016],
  press: [
    2021,
    2020,
    2019,
    2018,
    2017,
    2016,
    2015,
    2014,
    2013,
    2012,
    2011,
    2010,
    2009,
    2008,
    2007,
    2006
  ]
};

//change values in second menu based on first selection
function changeType(value) {
  if (value.length == 0)
    document.getElementById("selectYear").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (yearId in years[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option>" + years[value][yearId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("selectYear").innerHTML = catOptions;
  }
  
  // if (value !== '') {
  //   console.log(value);
  // } else {
  //   console.log('nothing happened');
  // }
}

//display results from filter
var storyTypeSelect = document.getElementById("selectStoryType");
var yearSelect = document.getElementById("selectYear");

function getStory() {
  display(storyTypeSelect.value, yearSelect.value);
}

function getYear() {
  display(storyTypeSelect.value, yearSelect.value);
}

function display(getStory, getYear) {
  Array.from(articles).forEach((article) => article.classList.remove('hidden'));
  
  if (getStory) {
    Array.from(articles)
      .filter((article) => !article.classList.contains(getStory))
      .forEach((article) => article.classList.add('hidden'));
  }
  
  if (getYear) {
    Array.from(articles)
      .filter((article) => !article.classList.contains(getYear))
      .forEach((article) => article.classList.add('hidden'));
  }
}
```

```css
/* filters */
.content {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.filter span {
  color: var(--grey-4);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--grey-6);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.filter select.filter__type,
.clear span {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  border: none;
}

.filter select.filter__type option {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  color: var(--grey-6);
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

section {
  margin: 5em 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  section.filter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 10vh;
    margin: 4em 0;
  }

  .clear span {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3px;
  }

  .filter select.filter__type,
  .clear span {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--grey-6);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="filter">
  <span>filter by</span>
  <select name="storyType" class="filter__type" id="storyType" onChange="changeType(this.value);">
    <option value="" selected disabled="disabled">Story Type</option>
    <option value="news">News and Media</option>
    <option value="analysis">Analysis</option>
    <option value="press">Press Releases</option>
  </select>

  <select name="year" class="filter__type" id="year">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
  </select>
  <div class="clear">
    <span>clear filters</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="results">
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <div class="results__content hidden">
    <div class="article news 2017">A news article from 2017.</div>
    <div class="article analysis 2019">An analysis article from 2019.</div>
    <div class="article press 2008">A press release from 2008.</div>  
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you give more context, where, what, who, why? What are criteria?! Also you have syntax error in fiddle.

Comment: The criteria is in the HTML.

Comment: @ikiK I fixed the syntax error. I'm still not able to see a result from the selection of dropdown items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was a bit messy and didn't pass first stage of populating years based on category. So i wrote it from stretch:

```
    const select = document.querySelector("#year")
    // fetch year selector
    let selectedCategory
    let selectedYear
    // declare two variables for later search
    function changeType(value) {
      console.clear()
      console.log(value)
      select.options.length = 0
    // empty the year select on every change
      select.innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>'
    // put first option in
      selectedCategory = value
    // save selected category for later search
      years[value].forEach(e => {
       console.log(e)
    // for each year in objects property by selected category
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = e;
        select.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", option)
    // create and insert options as years
      })
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".article")].forEach(article => article.classList.add("hidden")) // reset articles
    }
    
    function changeYear(value) {
      console.log(value)
      selectedYear = value;
    // on year change save selected Year variable 
      [...document.querySelectorAll("." + selectedCategory)].forEach(el => {
    // use category to select all divs that have class of your category
        console.log(el)
        el.classList.contains(selectedYear) ? el.classList.remove("hidden") : el.classList.add("hidden")
    // then check if divs have selected year, if not hide. 
      })
    }
```

Use code above for testing as it will console log every step

I have also moved `hidden` class from parent div to each inside, as it easier to just toggle that class on them for hide/show.

**Working fiddle:**

```js
var articles = document.getElementsByClassName("article");

var years = {
  news: [2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012],
  analysis: [2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016],
  press: [2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006]
};

const select = document.querySelector("#year")
let selectedCategory, selectedYear

function changeType(value) {
  select.options.length = 0
  select.innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>'
  selectedCategory = value
  years[value].forEach(e => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = e;
    select.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", option)
    
  });
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".article")].forEach(article => article.classList.add("hidden")) // reset articles
}

function changeYear(value) {
  selectedYear = value;
  [...document.querySelectorAll("." + selectedCategory)].forEach(el => {
    el.classList.contains(selectedYear) ? el.classList.remove("hidden") : el.classList.add("hidden")
  })
}
```

```css
/* filters */

.content {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.filter span {
  color: var(--grey-4);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--grey-6);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.filter select.filter__type,
.clear span {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  border: none;
}

.filter select.filter__type option {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  color: var(--grey-6);
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

section {
  margin: 5em 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  section.filter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 10vh;
    margin: 4em 0;
  }
  .clear span {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3px;
  }
  .filter select.filter__type,
  .clear span {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--grey-6);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="filter">
  <span>filter by</span>
  <select name="storyType" class="filter__type" id="storyType" onChange="changeType(this.value);">
    <option value="" selected disabled="disabled">Story Type</option>
    <option value="news">News and Media</option>
    <option value="analysis">Analysis</option>
    <option value="press">Press Releases</option>
  </select>

  <select name="year" class="filter__type" id="year" onChange="changeYear(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
  </select>
  <div class="clear">
    <span>clear filters</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="results">
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <div class="results__content">
    <div class="article news 2017 hidden">A news article from 2017.</div>
    <div class="article analysis 2019 hidden">An analysis article from 2019.</div>
    <div class="article press 2008 hidden">A press release from 2008.</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I agree. I was a ways off. I apologize for the messy code. I learned a few things. Thank you!

Comment: @JaredNewnam Np, I just noticed, I forgot to add reset on change of category.  Just put hidden class on all article's right at start when it comes to change,  other wise shown articles will stay shown after category change. Cheers. I edited the fiddle.

Comment: I ran into an issue where I need to display everything and filter out anything that isn't selected in the dropdown. I've been playing around with it, but I can't get it to cooperate. Can you assist?

Comment: @JaredNewnam Please ask another question with example and detailed explanation, then post link here, ill take a look when i find time.

Comment: Thanks. The new question is here: [Using JS, how can I set all items visible until they are filtered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275353/using-js-how-can-i-set-all-items-visible-until-they-are-filtered)